# Implementing UCCSD ansatz in Amazon Braket

Tags: qiskit, amazon-braket

Is there a way to directly implement UCCSD ansatz in braket, without manually defining the circuit? Like in qiskit, one can call [UCCSD](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/0.31/qiskit.chemistry.components.variational_forms.UCCSD) to create the ansatz circuit. Similarly can we do it in braket?

Note- Using qiskit-braket-provider is not an option as it is creating issues while deploying hybrid job.

Comment: Maybe not the more convenient, but creating the circuit with Qiskit, exporting it to QASM3 and importing it from the QASM3 into braket should be doable right? It should even be possible to write a function that implement this automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use PennyLane's implementation of UCCSD:
https://docs.pennylane.ai/en/stable/code/api/pennylane.UCCSD.html

And then use `amazon-braket-pennylane-plugin` to run this on Braket. More details here, including how to use this with a Braket hybrid job: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/braket/latest/developerguide/hybrid.html